# Set Null Value to query.setString for a named parameter in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

How to set Null Value to query.setString for a named parameter in Hibernate ?

Thanks,
Kathir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do, because in SQL you need a different syntax for null values. Examples in SQL:

```
select x.col from table x where x.string = 'text';
```

But with a null value you do

```
select x.col from table x where x.string is null;
```

As a consequence, you can't set null in named parameters in SQL. Also in Hibernate you need a different query when your string is null. For example:

```
String select;
if (s == null) {
  select = "from Table where column is null";
} else {
  select = "from Table where column = :string";
}
Query q = session.createQuery(s);
if (s != null) {
  q.setString("string", s);
}
```